# Rollback after coming out of the session in Oracle SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle19c

I am writing a wrapper shell or perl script which does open an oracle session using sqlplus and then execute some sql files by scanning a directory. So as part of this , lets say if we have multiple sql files in a directory,
for eg: first.sql,second.sql,third.sql
I am planning to create a single file(`AllSqlFilesInDirectory.sql`) with below content.

```
>cat AllSqlFilesInDirectory.sql
@first.sql
@second.sql
@third.sql
>
```

Now I am planning to run the file AllSqlFilesInDirectory.sql by opening an oracle sqlplus session.
After executing, I am planning to come out of the oracle sqlplus session  and I am planning to search  for any errors in the log file.
If there are any errors, I would like to execute rollback. But I think as I am out of that sqlplus session, rollback is not possible. I am just concerned about the DML statements that were executed as part of those multiple sql files in the directory.
So I have these doubts

1. Can I simply ignore and not be concerned about rollback at all
2. Can I do the rollback for a session which was already closed?
3. If above is valid, then how can do it?

Comment: Seems like a SQL\*Plus question and not a PL/SQL question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Can I simply ignore and not be concerned about rollback at all

That's a business question you'd have to answer.  If you want the changes to be rolled back if there is an error, you'd need to do a rollback.

> 2. Can I do the rollback for a session which was already closed?

As a practical matter, probably not.  Technically, you can using [flashback transaction backout](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/ha/flatxn/flatxn.htm) but that is generally way more complexity that you'd normally want to deal with.

> 3. If above is valid, then how can do it?

Rather than writing to a log file and parsing the log file to determine if there were any errors, it is most likely vastly easier to simply put a

```
whenever sqlerror exit rollback
```

at the top of your script.  That tells SQL*Plus to rollback the transaction and exit whenever an error is encountered.  You don't have to write logic to parse the log file.

[`Whenever sqlerror` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm)

Comment: If there will be some DDLs inbetween, all pending DMLs will be committed. So flashback is more appropriate for such task (and to keep the DB in consistent state).

Comment: Understood. But  if we ignore  handling DDL, its going to be a problem. So all DDL statements should be wrapped in an autonomous transaction.

Comment: @Vijay - What, exactly, is this process doing?  If you're the only one using the database because you're doing an upgrade of a large application, you could set a guaranteed restore point prior to the script starting and then restore to that in the event of a failure.

Comment: @JustinCave, This process is just a wrapper to execute any data fixes to the database tables. This process mainly want to log every activity of such data fixes.